# Allocate uri to image stream

Tags: c#, image, memory, stream, mapping

I have a image stream (and also buffer of that image) that I want to save in a ppt file. 
My problem is that to do so I need to have a path to the image.. 
My question is if there is any way to allocate a virtual path to a stream or buffer? Maybe using memory mapping?